# Any practical example for the POC of hashmap has no limit to store. Only limit is max heap?

Tags: hashmap

Q: hasCode() has return type int, it means we need to have max length of integer will be the limit for storing HashMap collection?? If I have more then 1000000 bn objects to store then how do we do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share some of the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: I have tried very simple example: